# Dynamic Range Select Issue When Only Single Row of Data

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an AdvancedFilter in Excel VBA code to produce a range of values, which are then dynamically selected and loaded into a ListBox. This is working well, unless there is only 1 row of data in the range; in which case, the ListBox will be loaded with 1 row of values followed by several blank rows of values. What can I do to correct this?

Code and supporting screenshots below:

```
Private Sub Condition_Change()

    ConditionDtl.Clear

    If Condition.Value <> "" Then

        'Filter Condition Detail list according to Condition selection
        Set ws5 = Worksheets("CondCondDtl")
        With ws5
            .Range("CritConditionDtl").Cells(2, 1).Value = Condition.Column(0)
            .Range("CritConditionDtl").Cells(2, 2).Value = Condition.Column(1)
            .Columns("A:D").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CriteriaRange:=.Range("CritConditionDtl"), CopyToRange:=.Range("CopyConditionDtl"), Unique:=True
        End With
        Set ws5 = Nothing

        'Load the new list of items into multiselect listbox
        ConditionDtl.List = Worksheets("CondCondDtl").Range("I2", _
            Worksheets("CondCondDtl").Range("I2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Value

    End If

End Sub
```

Data produced by AdvanceFilter:
[image: Data produced by AdvanceFilter]

ListBox with blank list items:
[image: ListBox with blank list items]

Comment: K.Davis: Changes suggested have been submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
With Worksheets("CondCondDtl")
    ConditionDtl.List =  .Range(.Range("I2"), .cells(rows.count, "J").End(xlUp)).Value
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and let you know how it turns out. :)